# Where clause in Eloquent does not seem to be working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Controller method like this for getting all the users who have set `adm` to 1:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('adm', '==', '1')->latest()->paginate(20);
        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

But now at the Blade, it shows all the entire users (also the ones who have not set `adm` to 1).

So why `where` clause does not work out correctly and selects the users with `adm` of 1 ? How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you can remove middle section  '=='

Comment: In general, there is a community preference not to answer off-topic questions. This one has been closed as "typo".